# 3 Divs, 2 Fixed width and 1 Fluid

Tags: html, css

I have a problem, where i am floating the first div(30px width) to the left, the third div(30px width) to the right and havin the second div take up the remaining space from the entire window width

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/AScBN/188/

```
.right
{
   height:40px;
   width:40px;
   float:left;
   background:green;
}

.left
{
   height:40px;
   width:40px;
   float:right;
   background:green;
}

.fluid
{
   margin-right: 50px;
   height:40px;
   background:red;
}

div
{
   border:1px solid yellow;
}
```

Problem:

I cant get them to sit beside each other, the last div gets pushed under obviously because of the fluid second div

Thanks

Aiden

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you got the orders wrong

```
<div class="right">1</div>
<div class="left">3</div>
<div class="fluid">3</div>
```

the non-floating div should be the last one.

Comment: hey there, this is working but why does it matter about the order in which the divs are placed?

Comment: In normal flow, block elements stack the next element under it.
So in your original code, div.fluid basically tells div.left to go to the next line where it floats to the right.
this [article](http://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101) can probably explain it better. Read under "how floats behave".

Answer (score 1):

Here's another incredibly easy way to do this using `Flex` - [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fishgraphics/zxk8kkcw/)

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="fixed">1. Fixed Right</div>
    <div class="fluid">2. Fluid</div>
    <div class="fixed">3. Fixed Left</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    height:40px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
.wrapper div {
    margin: auto;
    border:1px solid yellow;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
.fixed {
    width:40px;
    background:green;
}
.fluid {
    flex: 1;
    background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply `margin: 0 auto;` to your `.fluid`

Answer (score 0):

Put your "green" divs inside the "red" one. Set the overflow on the "red" one as block. Done.

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/AScBN/190/)**

```
<div class="fluid">2
    <div class="left">3</div>
    <div class="right">1</div>
</div>

.right {
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    float:left;
    background:green;
}
.left {
    height:40px;
    width:40px;
    float:right;
    background:green;
}
.fluid {
    overflow:block;
    height:40px;
    background:red;
    border:1px solid yellow;
}
```